# How to make specific item clickable on recyclerview?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I want make my like button clickable on recyclerview. When I click on recyclerview it shows that i clicked but how I can do it for a specific item on recyclerview, especially like imageview.

my adapter code:

```
class MasterAdapter(val arrayList: ArrayList<Model>, val context: Context) 
RecyclerView.Adapter<MasterAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    fun bindItems(model: Model) {

        itemView.locationTextSalonContainer.text = model.title
        itemView.descriptionSalon.text = model.des
        itemView.titleTextSalonContainer.text = model.name
        
itemView.descriptionIconSalonContainer.setImageResource(model.icon_circle)
        
itemView.titleIconSalonContainer.setImageResource(model.icon_building)
        itemView.salonContainerImage.setImageResource(model.image)
        itemView.textRating.text = model.rating
        itemView.textProfession.text = model.profession
        itemView.like.setImageResource(model.icon_heart)
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): 
ViewHolder {

    val v = 
LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.masters_recyclerview, 
parent, false)

    return ViewHolder(v)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return arrayList.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bindItems(arrayList[position])

    

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        if(position == 0 ) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked 1", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        if(position == 1) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked 2", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        if(position == 2) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked 3", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        if(position == 3) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked 4", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        if(position == 4) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked 5", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        if(position == 5) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked 6", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        if(position == 6) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked 7", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        if(position == 7) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "You clicked 8", 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
   }
}
```

How I can make it clickable? Is there any method? Waiting for answer, I will be pleased!sdsfascasfasfasfasfas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its quite simple actually, currently you're setting row's click listener

so you need to change it to specifically the ImageView, like this

```
holder.itemView.like.setOnClickListener {
   ...
}
```

Comment: sure, no problem :)